# OOP in Python. How do I do class method?

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to do a program (for a homework problem) that makes different Accounts and allows you to deposit/withdraw from it. I also am supposed to show the balance of all accounts when prompted with Account.totalAllBalance. Everything has been going fine but I am trying to figure out how to add the start balances to my totalAllBalance total. I keep getting this error and I'm not sure why. I am quite new to programming and I'm supposed to be using very basic programming we do in class. My question is why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

The error is at line 20 and it says

in **init**
    Account.totalAllBalance = Account.totalAllBalance + num
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'method' and 'int'

This is my attempt so far:

```
class Account:
    totalAllBalance = 0
    totalAccounts = 0

    def __init__(self, name, startBalance):
        self.name = name
        self.startBalance = startBalance
        num = startBalance
        if self.startBalance < .01:
            print("You may not start an account with that balance.")
        else :
            self.deposits = 0
            self.withdraws = 0
            Account.totalAccounts += 1
            if Account.totalAccounts is 1:
                Account.totalBalance = 0
            else:
               Account.totalAllBalance = Account.totalAllBalance + num

    def deposit(self, num):
        self.deposits += num
        print(self.name, "has deposited", num, "dollars.")
        Account.totalAllBalance = Account.totalAllBalance + num
        return(self.totalBalance())


    def withdraw(self, num):
        self.withdraws += num 
        if num > self.startBalance + -1*(self.withdraws-num) + self.deposits:
            print("You may not withdraw more than your balance.")
            self.withdraws -= num
        else:  
            num2= -1 * num
            print(self.name, "has withdrawn", num,"dollars.")
            return(self.totalBalance())
        Account.totalAllBalance = Account.totalAllBalance + num2

    def totalBalance(self):
        if self.withdraws is None:
            W = 0
        if self.deposits is None:
            D = 0
        S = self.startBalance 
        W = self.withdraws * -1 
        D = self.deposits
        num = S + W + D
        print(self.name,"has", S + W + D , "dollars in their account.")

    @classmethod
    def totalAllBalance(cls):
        print(cls.totalAllBalance)

    @classmethod
    def amtAccounts(cls):
        print("There is", cls.totalAccounts, "account(s).")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because you have `totalAllBalance` as both class method and class properties. In addition to that, the way you are accessing `Account.totalAllBalance` makes the compiler interpret is as method instead of properties. I would suggest to use `self.totalAllBalance` instead and have a different name for your class method (e.g. `printTotalAllBalance`)

```
def deposit(self, num):
    self.deposits += num
    print(self.name, "has deposited", num, "dollars.")
    self.totalAllBalance = self.totalAllBalance + num
    return(self.totalBalance())

@classmethod
def printTotalAllBalance(cls):
    print(cls.totalAllBalance)
```